# Fun with OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap, centos7

I have been setting up an OpenLDAP server on a system that already uses FreeIPA for user authentication. The purpose is to provide an authentication method for a spring application.

I have been noticing some odd things when run ldapadd and ldapmodify commands. I thought that this may have been related to a an incorrect password so I tried to update the olcRootPW.

I thought it might be a good idea to find the RootDN account and the current RootDN password hash:

```
sudo ldapsearch -H ldapi:// -LLL -Q -Y EXTERNAL -b "cn=config" "(olcRootDN=*)" dn olcRootDN olcRootPW
```

This returned:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=myldap,dc=local
olcRootPW: {SSHA}6amwprJqmgudYDYPbJaO3BgeAp6898
```

So far so good, so lets update the password with an ldif file - newpass.ldif:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}KPxel+B7Ua6Q9PPaM7xdaGSDqK0A1234
```

Run this command:

```
sudo ldapmodify -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL -f ~/newpass.ldif
```

So far so good, we get a success message:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"
```

Its a good idea to change the password in the normal DIT with this ldif:

```
dn: cn=Manager,dc=myldap,dc=local
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: {SSHA}KPxel+B7Ua6Q9PPaM7xdaGSDqK0A1234
```

When I apply this ldif with this command:

```
sudo ldapmodify -a -v -H ldap:/// -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=myldap,dc=local" -W -f ~/newpasswd.ldif
```

I get the following failure:

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://:389/??base )
Enter LDAP Password:
replace userPassword:
    {SSHA}KPxel+B7Ua6Q9PPaM7xdaGSDqK0A1234
modifying entry "cn=Manager,dc=myldap,dc=local"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
```

I have been seeing this a lot when using the "-D" switch and I can't figure out what is going on?

I saw the same thing when adding this ldif:

```
dn: dc=myldap,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: myldap.local

dc: myldap
dn: cn=Manager,dc=myldap,dc=local
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: Manager
description: Directory Manager

dn: ou=People,dc=myldap,dc=local
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People

dn: ou=Group,dc=myldap,dc=local
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Group
```

Running this command give the error:

```
sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=Manager,dc=myldap,dc=local -W -f baseldapdomain.ldif

Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: No such object (32)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to run the openLDAP on the same host as the application and then run slapd on a different local port:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h "ldapi:/// ldap:/// ldap://localhost:9090"
```

So when applying ldif files this works:

```
sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=Manager,dc=cdfldap,dc=local -H ldap://localhost:9090 -W -f baseldapdomain.ldif
```

I am still have issues starting slapd using systemd with a custom port but that can wait for now.

Comment: Removing the /// hosts from the service file has allowed just the custom port configuration to work: [Unit]
Description=Custom openLDAP Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slapd -h "ldap://LDAP_IP:9090"
User=ldap

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target